# VBA - Union de dois ranges não adjacentes e colagem transposta em outra planilha

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Com o intuito de minimizar a quantidade de seleções para uma planilha numa iteração por 75000 registros, eu estou tentando fazer a união de dois ranges não adjacentes (2 colunas distintas, num total de 10 linhas) em uma planilha cujos valores serão colados em outra planilha de forma transposta e adjacente, numa tabela (1 linha e 10 colunas).

```
Dim Vpo As Worksheet
Dim Resultados As Worksheet
Dim DadosResultados As Range

Set Vpo = Sheets("VPO - ATI")
Set Resultados = Sheets("Resultados Individuais")

Set DadosResultados = Appplication.Union(Vpo.Range("I9:I10"), _
    Vpo.Range("Q17:Q24"))

Resultados.Cells(Contagem, 9).Value = Application _
    .WorksheetFunction.Transpose(DadosResultados)
```

Esse método não está se mostrando útil, dado que apesar de não haver erro de execução, os valores não estão sendo colados.

Gostaria de ajudar para tentar entender melhor o problema.

Ressalto que copiar e colar duas vezes, uma para cada coluna, dá certo, mas o tempo de execução para a quantidade de registros é muito grande.

Abaixo está o código mencionado no parágrafo anterior:

```
Resultados.Cells(11, 9).Value = Vpo.Range("I9").Value
Resultados.Cells(11, 10).Value = Vpo.Range("I10").Value

Vpo.Range("Q17:Q24").Copy

Resultados.Range("I11").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlValues _
    SkipBlanks:=False
```

Comment: Qual o valor de `Contagem` em `Resultados.Cells(Contagem, 9).Value`?

Comment: Inicia na linha 11 e termina na contagem total de linhas da tabela consultada.

Comment: Mas quando que `Contagem` é incrementado no seu código? Na verdade nem precisa incrementar e utilizar a contagem...